# C# Building images dynamically and returning to view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement where I need to generate a custom image (or several images) when a user hits our page. The user is emailed a special link, that link has the users encrypted id as one of the parameters so we can distinguish who is accessing our site.

We must build an image that is unique to that user (their name, specific icons, etc).

I am currently accomplishing this by using string interpolation. I have an SVG template with values such as @UserName, @Icon1, etc. I then pass that raw SVG data to my View and wrap it around @Html.Raw() to render the custom image.

I am interested if there is a more efficient way of doing this, CPU and memory usage seem fine in my testing but I am concerned when this scales we will see a bottle neck or other issues that weren't discovered in development. The SVG is fairly large about 9500 characters, and there are cases where we are sending up to 10 different images on one single request.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    string svgTemplate = GetTemplateFromDb(id);
    svgTemplate = svgTemplate.Replace("@Name", "SomeName").Replace("@Address", "SomeAddress");

    BuiltItem images = Build(svgTemplate);

    return View(images);

}
```

View:

```
<div>
    @Html.Raw(Model.data)
</div>
```

Comment: implement a TAP pattern (?)

Comment: @DaniDev TAP will help with building the docs fast enough, but i'm more concerned with how cpu and memory will act if we have hundreds of people accessing the page at the same time and if there are any network issues with serving several 9000 char svgs per request. I'm interested if there is a preferred or standard way for the building the documents, like a service that builds the documents in advance or not using SVG because of known issues.. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nine thousand chars isn't all that much. If they're unsigned chars, you're looking at about 9kB. If they're unicode, 54kB at most. Most webpages are at least a few MB. Even if you're sending 10 of them, you're looking at 90kB if you're using regular chars or half a megabyte with unicode.

Generally people advise not prematurely optimizing. This could be one of of those times. If it ends up being a bottleneck, you'll know and you can revisit it, maybe try to trim your SVG template down a bit.